# Mysql select count per category per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

`categories` table

> id | name

`items` table

> id | name | category_id

`orders` table

> id | item_id | date_time | transaction_code

Now how can I select total order's with specific transaction code for each category for every day in my query.

Desired results:

```
Date        Category Total
2013-12-01  001      6
2013-12-01  002      0
2013-12-01  003      1
2013-12-02  001      14
2013-12-02  002      2
2013-12-02  003      0
2013-12-03  001      11
2013-12-03  002      4
2013-12-03  003      4
```

What would be the most efficient way to write this query.

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT DATE(od.trans_date) AS Date, ct.number AS Category, COUNT(od.id) AS Total 
from orders od
JOIN items im ON od.item_id = im.id
JOIN categories ct ON im.category_id = ct.id
WHERE od.trans_date BETWEEN '2013-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
AND (od.transaction_code = 17 OR od.transaction_code = 15)
GROUP BY DATE(od.trans_date), ct.number ASC;
```

Thank you

Comment: your results are **off**??? How so???

Comment: I know I have some categories with zero orders but I don't get a single zero

Comment: If they don't have orders, then they won't have a transaction_date, so they don't meet your where conditions.  Your probably need to switch which direction you are joining.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your `JOINS` to `LEFT JOINS` so that your results will include orders that do not have any items...

```
SELECT DATE(od.trans_date) AS Date, ct.number AS Category, COUNT(od.id) AS Total 
from orders od
LEFT JOIN items im ON od.item_id = im.id
LEFT JOIN categories ct ON im.category_id = ct.id
WHERE od.trans_date BETWEEN '2013-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
AND (od.transaction_code = 17 OR tr.transaction_code = 15)
GROUP BY DATE(od.trans_date), ct.number ASC;
```

Also, you might need to switch the order of your `JOINS` so that all categories show up, and not all orders.

```
SELECT DATE(od.trans_date) AS Date, ct.number AS Category, COUNT(od.id) AS Total 
FROM categories ct
LEFT JOIN items im ON ct.id = im.category_id
LEFT JOIN orders od ON im.id = od.item_id
WHERE od.trans_date BETWEEN '2013-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
AND (od.transaction_code = 17 OR tr.transaction_code = 15)
GROUP BY DATE(od.trans_date), ct.number ASC;
```

Comment: This shows only the categories that have at least 1 order on that day. I need the count for every day, for each category that has at least one order between date1 and date2.

Comment: if you need the results for each day then you should use the top query, basically whichever table you `SELECT` `FROM`, it will contain all records from that table, the `LEFT JOIN`'s tack on results from those tables where there are matches...